Azure AI Studio - Adding more files to an existing index through UI
Using Azure AI Studio, I create a data source and connections to azure blob storage. Go to Chat, select source and automatically create index. I select 1 time run, it indexes the data and I'm able to chat with it through the playground.
Please give detailed step-by-step instructions on how to add additional data (adding files to existing path or pointing to another blob path) and reindex it reusing the same index, preferably through the Azure AI Studio or ML Studio UI, so it only updates the existing index without having to reprocess all the files.
Things I've tried:
I uploaded new files to an existing blob storage and I was able to create a new version in the data source pointing to the same blob storage and I can see the new files in the explorer. But I want to update my existing index again, manually, without creating a new one.
I tried created a scheduled job. I expected it to update index and reflect current files. Started with 4 files, ran the initial job later deleted 1 of the files with the scheduled job, the index still has 4 files. The job didn't reuse any of the existing files, it's set to force-run though. When I set it not to force rerun, it just reuses exiting jobs and does nothing, it doesn't detect file changes.



Yes, you can do rerun the indexer to add new documents to current index itself.
After, uploading the files to blob storage you rerun the indexer or reset and rerun to reindex all documents.
Below is the number of documents initially i was having.

After uploading the documents i done rerun and the new document indexed.

if you do reset and rerun then all documents will reindexed with new documents.


does it know if a file is delete?

Yes, it identifies the deleted file and removes it from index, only when you check mark the Enable deletion tracking in the data source configuration. Also you should -   Enable soft delete for blobs.

After deleting the one document i rerun the indexer and got success on removing it.

You learn more about this here.

It looks like you are showing Azure Cognitive Search, not Azure AI Studio. The question was about steps starting from Azure AI Studio. A cognitive search indexer is not created when starting from Azure AI Studio.

Now Azure Cognitive Search is renamed to azure ai search. And LLM crack chunk component is not meant for handling the data source missing or new files it just used to chunk the large document.

Like I mentioned you need to enable deletion tracking in the data source for handling missing files. Indexer is created when you are having index please check it.

I just checked and there are no indexers in Azure AI Search when creating data from Azure AI Studio. Please revise your answer to focus on Azure AI Studio. Steps: go to AI chat playground, add your own data source (blob). It creates a job and indexes data automatically. No indexers created in Azure AI Search.

You can not alter the documents without indexer. It is core component while indexing the documents. When you select blob storage as data source in chat playground it temporarily uses indexer and deletes it. So my idea here is you create a index on your own with data sources and using indexer then in AI studio chat playground select AI search as data source and give the index name you created.

In your approach every single time you need to create index when using in chat playground instead of it you create an index on your own like I mentioned configurations then give AI search as source in chat playground.

Jaya, that is what i was trying to avoid. I should be able to update an existing index and add data in ML Studio. Whats the point of having a scheduler? I want to do everything from AI Studio/ML Studio. I like that AI Studio sets up a good enough index with proper fields and embeddings automatically. Doing this through AI Search feels backwards and more work.

If you don't want to touch ai search then each and every single time you just need to add your data source in chat playground. If add more files remove the data source again add it, if you delete the file you remove it and add it again. Please refer what ai search is and how it works in the documentation before you start using it. You can't update existing index through ai studio.
